# How can I do a multiple filter product in liquid?

Tags: filter, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to have multiple tag selector that you can filter if is round and red at the same time, but only one filter selector works. Anyone knows how can I do it ??

```
    <label>Shop by color</label>
      <select name="SortTags" id="SortTags"  >
      {% assign tags = 'Red, Green, Blue' | split: ',' %}
      <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">All</option>
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
      {% if current_tags contains tag %}
      <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tag }}</option>
      {% elsif collection.all_tags contains tag %}
      <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }} / {{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</option>
      {%endif%}
      {%endfor%}
    </select>

    
   <label>Shop by size</label>
    <select name="SortTags" id="SortTags" >
    {% assign tags = 'Round, square, geometric' | split: ',' %}
      <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">All</option>
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
      {% if current_tags contains tag %}
      <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tag }}</option>
      {% elsif collection.all_tags contains tag %}     
      <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }} / {{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</option>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </select>  
 
 
      <label>Shop by material</label>
    <select name="SortTags" id="SortTags" >
    {% assign tags = 'White, leopard, Satin' | split: ',' %}
      <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }}">All</option>
      {% for t in tags %}
      {% assign tag = t | strip %}
      {% if current_tags contains tag %}
      <option value="{{ tag | handle }}" selected>{{ tag }}</option>
      {% elsif collection.all_tags contains tag %}        
      <option value="/collections/{{ collection.handle }} / {{ tag | handle }}">{{ tag }}</option>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Thanks for all.